# i5 760 or i5 2500

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5

I am planing to buy computer this days, and i was thinking about i5 760 processor.

Now I think that maybe it is good idea to wait for i5 2500 processor. For same money I will get better processor with new architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I wouldn't say is in same league, it seems it's superior in performance even to i7 870, and indeed, seems several tests give results equal (seems on par if not better than 950, and even saw similar result in some department with 980X :o ) to what very high end cpus give...

So, if purchasing new comp, no doubt, a 2500, or better, 2600k might be the right purchase. This has come as a surprise to most reviewers.

Just dig well the info, as it might be non compatible -in real life- with old mother boards and other stuff. And also, things to look are cache, that 2500 does not have 8 threads, but four (no hyper threading, though this year not a lot of applications will use more than four)

Its default per core speed is very fast and they say, very optimized. The benchmarks are jaw dropping, and is not as expensive as I was thinking. Seems around 270$ and less for the 2500...maybe quite much more than 300$ the 2600, but this will vary a lot, and fast...

But dig well all info before purchasing. Looks like for same money, or even some less, purchase a i5 760 would be an error unless you're very limited to a specific amount of bucks.